# Selecting data based on related table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, relational-database, entity-relationship

I have the following tables:

```
posts
---------------------
id   |   name
---------------------
1    |   First Post
2    |   Another post 

tags
---------------------
id   |   name
---------------------
1    |   Tag1
2    |   Tag2
3    |   Tag3

posts_tags
---------------------
post_id | tag_id
---------------------
1       |   2
1       |   3
2       |   1
3       |   2
```

I'm trying to write a query that (in human readable terms) would say something like 'Find all of the posts which are tagged with tag1 or tag2'.

So I can put multiple tag IDs in and get a lists of posts that have at least one of those tags back.

I've tried this:

```sql
 SElECT t1.name 
   FROM posts AS t1 INNER JOIN posts_tags AS t2 
     ON t1.id = t2.post_id 
  WHERE t2.tag_id IN(1,2)
```

But this returns no results. I'm not really sure where to go from here. Is there any way I can do this in one query - i.e without first fetching the posts, then looping through them to fetch the tags?

Comment: You're not creating a `t1` alias in your query, so as written the whole thing is a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo I made when I put it into stack overflow. The actual code doesn't have this typo, i've fixed it now. Thanks

Comment: You need to join on posts_tags, not tags.

Comment: will yo only ve three tags ,tag_id like 1,2,3 ??just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `IN` operator:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM posts_tags
WHERE tag_id IN (1,2,3)
```

To avoid getting `post_id` duplicates use the `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT post_id
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   t1.post_id 
FROM 
   posts_tags as t1
INNER JOIN 
   posts AS t2 
ON 
   t1.post_id = t2.id    
WHERE 
   t2.tag_id IN(1,2)
```

By Joining the Posts table you now have access to all of the post data, which I assume is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you have to join `posts_tags` table also.

```
 SElECT t1.name FROM posts as t1 INNER JOIN posts_tags as t3 on t3.post_id = t1.id INNER JOIN tags AS t2 ON t2.id = t3.tag_id WHERE t2.id IN(1,2)
```

SQLFiddle answer here.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d785e/5

Comment: Sorry, that was also a typo. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT posts.name FROM posts LEFT JOIN post_tags ON posts.id = post_tags.post_id WHERE post_tags.tag_id = '1' OR post_tags.tag_id = '2'
```

Comment: An OUTER JOIN here is superfluous to requirements, given what comes after it.

Comment: LEFT JOIN was used on purpose in case the tag names in the 'tags' table don't always match the tag_id (ie. ID 1 could be Tag 7) in which case you'd need to do a left join to the tags table as well to search by tag name (rather than ID). Superfluous, perhaps, but useful for his data scheme. LEFT JOIN solves his problem and it prepares for future possibilities in adjusting the query.

Comment: Unfortunately, your WHERE clause nullifies that ambition

Comment: Agreed, the WHERE clause would be amended in that event.

Comment: Well, you may as well amend the JOIN at the same time !?! Keep up the good work - and also check out the `IN` comparison as described above.